# Create a random token in Javascript based on user details

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, token

I want to create a random string (token) which can be used to identify a user whilst avoiding any potential conflicts with any other users' tokens.

What I was thinking of was an MD5 hash of `navigator.userAgent + new Date().getTime()` to generate the token but that requires a whole Javascript MD5 library to hash it which I don't really want to do.

It has to be made up of A-Z/0-9 characters and ideally no longer than 32 characters. I am open to all ideas. Thanks!

**Just to clarify I'm not looking for any random string generator, the random string has to be generated from the users details available through Javascript and can also use time to avoid potential conflicts!**

Comment: as you have written, the only thing that comes to my mind is a hash function. you might want to try to google something like "hash function javascript" and maybe you will find sometihng lightweight

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout [crypto.js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) project. Its a collection of cryptographic algorithms. The project has separate js files for each hashing algorithms.

Comment: Ok i've resigned myself to using MD5, crypto looks like a small library thanks!

Comment: Don't use md5. It's not collision-resistant.

Answer (score 146):

You could generate a random number and convert it to base 36 (`0-9a-z`):

```
var rand = function() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2); // remove `0.`
};

var token = function() {
    return rand() + rand(); // to make it longer
};

token(); // "bnh5yzdirjinqaorq0ox1tf383nb3xr"
```

Comment: @fire: I think this doesn't practically cause conflicts. MD5 theoratically can also cause conflicts, but you shouldn't need to worry about that.

Comment: It could conflict, if the token was generated through someones own browser information + your method that would be better.

Comment: @fire: I don't fully get your point. `navigator.userAgent` isn't unique for everyone, so it doesn't make it bulletproof.

Comment: Removing `radix` (`36`) parameter from `.toString` in `rand` function will give you numeric-only hash -- if someone would like for the one like that: `return Math.random().toString().substr(2);`

Comment: Man I love a sweet one-liner!

Answer (score 13):

I use an approach similar to [Kareem's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46874407/1161948), but with fewer function calls and built-in array operations for a big boost in performance.

According to a [performance test](https://jsperf.com/js-random-token), this method also outperforms the accepted answer by a small margin. Moreover it provides a parameter `n` to generate any size token length from a white list of acceptable characters. It's flexible and performs well.

```
function generateToken(n) {
    var chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    var token = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        token += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    }
    return token;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This function allows you to set the token length and allowed characters.

```
function generate_token(length){
    //edit the token allowed characters
    var a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".split("");
    var b = [];  
    for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
        var j = (Math.random() * (a.length-1)).toFixed(0);
        b[i] = a[j];
    }
    return b.join("");
}
```

Simply call generate_token

```
generate_token(32); //returns "qweQj4giRJSdMNzB8g1XIa6t3YtRIHPH"
```

Comment: The other answer is smaller and faster, but I like the fact that this one lets you choose the length and the allowed characters.

Answer (score 11):

```js
//length: defines the length of characters to express in the string

const rand=()=>Math.random(0).toString(36).substr(2);
const token=(length)=>(rand()+rand()+rand()+rand()).substr(0,length);

console.log(token(40));
//example1:  token(10) => result: tsywlmdqu6
//example2:  token(40) => result: m4vni14mtln2547gy54ksclhcv0dj6tp9fhs1k10
```

Answer (score 4):

It is very unlikely, but Math.random() could return `0.0`. In that case, the solution of [pimvdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514749/pimvdb) would return `""` (empty string). So, here is another solution, which returns in every case a random base36 with 10 chars length:

```
function generateToken() {
    return Math.floor(1000000000000000 + Math.random() * 9000000000000000)
          .toString(36).substr(0, 10)
}
```