# Create token on textbox focusout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, token, jquery-tokeninput

I'm populating email-id in the text box value using `ng-repeat`. Using the edit icon I'm adding an email-id in the text box and on the text box focus out I have to create a token for the email-id in the text box.
I have to find out the token input and create the token

```js
$(".tagemail")
  .parent()
  .focusout(function () {
    $(".token-input").each(function (valindex) {
      if ($(this).val() != "") {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#" + id).val("");
        thisChild.tokenfield("createToken", value);
      }
    });
  });
```

But the div of **thisChild** getting differed.

Comment: What is the question here? Please consider reformatting it.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not formulated correctly but I think this is what you are looking for this:

https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

You can create all kinds of tokens

Or generate a random number:

```js
var rand = function () {
  return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2); // remove `0.`
};

var token = function () {
  return rand() + rand(); // to make it longer
};

token(); // "bnh5yzdirjinqaorq0ox1tf383nb3xr"
```

Source: [Already Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532406/create-a-random-token-in-javascript-based-on-user-details)